# matomo-tracker-react useMatomo returns "Invalid hook call"

Tags: reactjs, npm, react-hooks, react-router, matomo

im trying to implement matomo analytics within my react application (cra), however it trows an invalid hook call exception. Code has been copied from the simple example
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@datapunt/matomo-tracker-react

Did i miss something?

react: 17.0.2
react-dom: 17.0.2

code:

Index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";

import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import store from "./redux/store";

import { MatomoProvider, createInstance } from "@datapunt/matomo-tracker-react";

const matomo = createInstance({
  urlBase: "http://192.168.133.226/",
  siteId: 3,
  heartBeat: {
    active: true,
    seconds: 10,
  },
  linkTracking: false,
  configurations: {
    disableCookies: true,
    setSecureCookie: true,
    setRequestMethod: "POST",
  },
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <MatomoProvider value={matomo}>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </MatomoProvider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

App.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import "./App.scss";

import { BrowserRouter as Router, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { useMatomo } from "@datapunt/matomo-tracker-react";

import Navigation from "./components/navigation/navigation";
import Sitemap from "./components/sitemap/sitemap";

import Main from "./pages/main/main";

function App() {
  const modal = useSelector((state) => state.modal);
  const items = useSelector((state) => state.items);
  const app = useSelector((state) => state.app);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const { trackPageView } = useMatomo();

  useEffect(() => {
    trackPageView();

    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className='app'>
      <Router>
        <Navigation />
        <Sitemap />
        <Main />
      </Router>

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the Matamo instance first and then wrap everything around that.
Refer this https://www.npmjs.com/package/@datapunt/matomo-tracker-react

Comment: I've post the index.js file as well. The instance has been copied from the npm exapmle.

Comment: Ohh, my bad. I guess this has something to do with the Navigation component because the new version of the react-router-dom has the Navigation component. If that is not the case, can you please also share the other components.

Comment: I've tried to remove the navigation, however the exception is still there. Perhaps matomo is not working in combination with redux?

Comment: Hi there, any updates on this? I don't have any event outgoing even if the configuration is exactly as the one on the documentation. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/jonkoops/matomo-tracker/tree/main/packages/react

Use this one & try again:

- npm install @jonkoops/matomo-tracker-react
- import { MatomoProvider, createInstance } from '@jonkoops/matomo-tracker-react'
- import { useMatomo } from '@jonkoops/matomo-tracker-react'